# Prettier prints to the console with python, any ideas?

Tags: python, console-application

I have a 10x10 np array which consists of dots and characters. The characters move in a random pattern, after every move i print the array to the consol, but it looks laggy and weird, i wanted to ask if you guys know a way how i can make this look prettier? Im only allowed to use standard python libraries.

```
class World:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.world = np.empty((self.x, self.y), dtype=object)
        self.world.fill(None)
```

Here i created the array, which is filled with symbols or nothing

```
def print_world(self):
        for i in range(self.x):
            for j in range(self.y):
                if self.world[i, j] == None:
                    print('.', end=' ')
                else:
                    print(self.world[i, j].symb, end=' ')
            print()
```

this is the actual print, and my question is how i can make this look prettier, regarding its lagginess not its visuals. Thank you

Comment: Would you consider `turtle` a standard library?  Barring something like that, you might build up the string you want to print in it's entirety and print it all at once.  calling print is slow.

Comment: `numpy` isn't part of Python's standard library

Comment: @spencerlou indeed, but this a homework project and we are allowed to use numpy for this

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: @JonSG nothing except for numpy,time and random is allowed for this porject

Comment: You don't need numpy to create/use a 10x10 array, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer true but its easier and allowed so i used it

Comment: @Knapapa teachers love SO

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **JonSG** avoid calling multiple `print` should improve lag.

```py
def print_world(self):
    world_str = str()
    for x in range(self.x):
        for y in range(self.y):
            if self.world[x, y] is None:
                world_str += ". "
            else:
                world_str += self.world[x, y].symb
        world_str += "\n"
    print(world_str)
```

Comment: This makes the print smoother yes, but the problem is more about the lag/twitching that happens when i print the world again. Do you have anything useful for that?

Comment: @Knapapa Unclear what you mean by this. Sounds like a terminal problem, rather than something Python can solve. If you need to dynamically refresh the terminal, that's what the curses library I linked in the comments can do...